# node js express reg.body is undefined

Tags: node.js, express

отправляю запрос в postman. В ответ жду данные которые отправил но ответ пустой.

[image: запрос в postman]

```
const express = require('express')

const app = express()

const PORT = 3000

app.use(express.json());

app.post('/api/login', (req, res) => {
  res.json({body: req.body})
})

app.listen(PORT)
console.log("Server start on port: " + PORT)
```

Comment: Ну надо определиться, form-data или json?  А то вы отправляете первое, а скрипт ожидает второе

Comment: @AlexeyTen хочу form-data. как мне исправить код?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#readme